# openstack existing instance image clone to new instances instance1=instance2

Tags: instance, clone, openstack

I have a instance in openstack, Instance A, In instance A we have installed some tools, the same set of tools/OS we need it to the instance B, basically we have to replicate the same to instance B.

How we can do through gui or cmd line

I need configuration should be Instance A=Instance B

We already tried, we have created snapshot and launched the same, but not able to ssh the floating IP

WE have created volume (copy) and launched, not able login.